# Can we fit the worldhood of the world in the world we have in common?

Tags: heidegger, phenomenology, being-and-time

> Is 'world' perhaps a charac­teristic of Dasein's Being ? And in that
>   case, does every Dasein 'proximally' have its world ? Does not 'world'
>   thus become something 'subjective' ? How, then, can there be a
>   'common' world 'in' which, nevertheless, we are ? And if we raise the
>   question of the 'world', what world do we have in view ? Neither the
>   common world nor the subjective world, but the world­hood of the
>   world as such.

Being and Time p64.

Can this worldhood of the world as such, which interests Heidegger, be made to fit with the world we are in in common?

I'm asking because I am trying to find out where Heidegger says that the world is never a perceptual object in its own right. Apparently section 28, cited by Jameson The Political Unconscious p98. Knowing the answer to this question should also enrich my intuitive grasp on what it is Heidegger is trying to do.

Comment: Can you unpack a little more why this is an interesting/important question to you, and what exactly you'd like an explanation about?

Comment: i explicitly did, in the last paragraph. sorry, i have no idea what you mean

Comment: @JosephWeissman it would help me to understand these sections on "worldhood" to know how this existentiale fits in the objective world. i'm sorry if in any way that sounds crazy

Comment: Here is Cavalier's commentary on Sein und Zeit http://caae.phil.cmu.edu/Cavalier/80254/Heidegger/DivisionOne/Worldhood.html At first blush "*the worldhood of the world as such*" sounds like a Husserlian essence, neither subjective nor social, but ideal. But of course it can't be, by 1927 Heidegger already rejected Husserl's essentialism. But he needed a replacement, "existentials" in place of categories and essences of old metaphysics, "*Worldhood is to be seen as an existential structure of Dasein*". It can't "fit" into the vulgar common world, even readiness to hand goes beyond perception.